# How can I access objects in FormCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a collection of form items I am submitting to my controller action that looks something like this:

```
FormData: {
  Person: {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    address: ""
  },
  Inquiries: {
    {
      field_one: "",
      field_two: "",
      field_three: ""
    },
    {
      field_one: "",
      field_two: "",
      field_three: ""
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to access these inquiries in the action like `formCollection["Inquiries"][0]` or `formCollection["Inquiries"]` and then iterate through them individually but the keys I am getting are in the form 
 of `Inquiries[0].field_one` . 
**Is there a way around this?**

[image]

Comment: You could always use a class to get mapping from your formData to this class - it's way nicer than acessing raw formdata.
but if you work with the formdata, the abstraction looks correct - your inquiries have two subobjects, which are in an array

Comment: @ChristianSauer I forgot to mention Inquiry fields are dynamically generated, pulled from the database based on other input so using a class wouldn't be a best solution.

Comment: What about a dict? Class Abc { public Dictionary <string, string> Inquiries } Btw for your case an array of dicts

Comment: @ChristianSauer could you explain how I could implement it.
 public Dictionary<string, string>[] Inquiries { get; set; } returns Inquiries > [0], [1] but null